# Add style to body based on url

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, javascript

I recently installed a plugin on my wordpress website
Look like the developer of this plugin have no creativity. I want to add class to the body based on url so i can customize the template of each page
I tried windows.location in javascript , When i call alert() in windows.location , it work fine but when use $(body').addClass , Its not working
What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

for your home page:
On index.php or your home page custom file use:

```
if (is_home()){
  echo 'hi home!';
}
```

for any other page except 404:
use the file page.php or the custom one:
for example the link is [www.xyz.pt/chat/](http://www.xyz.pt/chat/)

```
if (is_page('chat')){
  echo 'hi page!';
}
```

for page 404:

```
if (is_404()){
  echo 'hi error 404';
}
```